# Nodejs usage using the source code

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded the node js source code. I don't have permission to install .msi or .exe veriosn here.

So how to use the node js

Please help.

Comment: Any insights what you already tried?  Did you follow the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile it first.

on windows, you need Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 (Express is the free version) installed, as well as python 2.7.x.

Go into the node source directory and run `vcbuild.bat nosign release x64` for 64 bit and `vcbuild.bat nosign release` for 32 bit.

Source: [Wiki on the Node.js GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#building-on-windows)